# Error creating AWS CloudFormation Stack (AMI cannot be described)

Tags: amazon-web-services

I want to create a Amazon Web Services stack (CloudFormation)  (clicking the New Stack Button to create a new AWS CLoudFormation Stack)
based on this template:

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion" : "2010-09-09",
  "Description" : "AWS CodeDeploy infra",
  "Parameters" : {
    "VPCID": {
      "Description" : "VPC ID",
      "Type": "String",
      "Default": "vpc-16438e72"
    },

    "myIP": {
      "Description" : "Enter your IP address in CIDR notation, e.g. 100.150.200.225/32",
      "Type": "String",
      "Default": "50.186.16.59/32"
    },

    "InstanceProfile": {
      "Description" : "Use the full ARN for SimpleCodeDeployInstanceProfile or AdvancedCodeDeployInstanceProfile",
      "Type": "String",
      "Default": "arn:aws:iam::663934185745:instance-profile/SimpleCodeDeployInstanceProfile"
    },

    "KeyName" : {
      "Description" : "Name of an existing EC2 KeyPair to enable SSH access to the instances",
      "Type" : "AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName",
      "ConstraintDescription" : "The name of an existing EC2 KeyPair.",
      "Default": "alexdglover"
    },
    "AZ"  : {
      "Description" : "Comma delimited list of AvailabilityZones where the instances will be created",
      "Type"        : "CommaDelimitedList",
      "Default": "us-east-1a,us-east-1c,us-east-1d"
    },

    "PublicSubnets"  : {
      "Description" : "Comma delimited list of public subnets",
      "Type"        : "CommaDelimitedList",
      "Default": "subnet-6fa38e36,subnet-4ba2f160,subnet-13b1ba64"
    },

    "InstanceType" : {
      "Description" : "Provide InstanceType to be used",
      "Type" : "String",
      "ConstraintDescription" : "Must be a valid EC2 instance type, such as t2.medium",
      "Default": "t2.medium"
    },

    "LinuxAMIID" : {
      "Description" : "Linux AMI ID",
      "Type" : "String",
      "Default": "ami-e3106686"
    },
    "WindowsAMIID" : {
      "Description" : "Windows AMI ID",
      "Type" : "String",
      "Default": "ami-f7482692"
    }
  },
  "Resources" : {
  "WebSecurityGroup": {
    "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
    "Properties": {
      "GroupDescription": "WebSecurityGroup",
      "SecurityGroupEgress": [
        {
          "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0",
          "FromPort": -1,
          "IpProtocol": "-1",
          "ToPort": -1
        }
      ],
      "SecurityGroupIngress": [
        {
          "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0",
          "FromPort": 80,
          "IpProtocol": "6",
          "ToPort": 80
        },
        {
          "CidrIp": {
            "Ref": "myIP"
          },
          "IpProtocol": "-1"
        }
      ],
      "VpcId": {
        "Ref": "VPCID"
      }
    }
    },

    "LinuxWebSNSTopic" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::SNS::Topic"
    },
    "LinuxWebASG" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup",
      "Properties" : {
        "AvailabilityZones" : { "Ref" : "AZ" },
        "VPCZoneIdentifier" : { "Ref": "PublicSubnets" },
        "MinSize" : "3",
        "MaxSize" : "3",
        "HealthCheckType" : "ELB",
        "HealthCheckGracePeriod" : "600",
        "NotificationConfiguration" : {
          "TopicARN" : { "Ref" : "LinuxWebSNSTopic" },
          "NotificationTypes" : [
            "autoscaling:EC2_INSTANCE_LAUNCH",
            "autoscaling:EC2_INSTANCE_LAUNCH_ERROR",
            "autoscaling:EC2_INSTANCE_TERMINATE",
            "autoscaling:EC2_INSTANCE_TERMINATE_ERROR"
          ]
      },
      "LoadBalancerNames" : [ { "Ref" : "LinuxWebELB" } ],
      "DesiredCapacity" : "3",
      "LaunchConfigurationName" : { "Ref" : "LinuxWebLaunchConfig" },
      "Tags" : [
        {"Key" : "Name", "Value" : "LinuxWebServer", "PropagateAtLaunch" : "true" }
      ]
     }
    },
    "LinuxWebLaunchConfig": {
      "Properties": {
        "AssociatePublicIpAddress" : "true",
        "ImageId": { "Ref": "LinuxAMIID" },
        "InstanceType": { "Ref": "InstanceType" },
        "KeyName": { "Ref": "KeyName" },
        "SecurityGroups": [ { "Ref": "WebSecurityGroup" } ],
        "IamInstanceProfile": { "Ref": "InstanceProfile" },
        "UserData": {
          "Fn::Base64": {
            "Fn::Join": [
              "",
              [
                "#!/bin/bash\n\n",
                "yum update -y\n\n",
                "yum install httpd -y\n\n",
                "yum install ruby\n\n",
                "yum install aws-cli\n\n",
                "cd ~\n\n",
                "aws s3 cp s3://aws-codedeploy-us-east-1/latest/install . --region us-east-1\n\n",
                "chmod +x ./install\n\n",
                "./install auto\n\n",
                "echo 'hello world' > /var/www/html/index.html\n\n",
                "hostname >> /var/www/html/index.html\n\n",
                "chkconfig httpd on\n\n",
                "service httpd start\n\n"
              ]
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "Type": "AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration"
    },

    "LinuxWebAutoscaleUpPolicy" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::AutoScaling::ScalingPolicy",
      "Properties" : {
        "AdjustmentType" : "ChangeInCapacity",
        "AutoScalingGroupName" : { "Ref" : "LinuxWebASG" },
        "Cooldown" : "300",
        "ScalingAdjustment" : "1"
      }
    },
    "LinuxWebAutoscaleDownPolicy" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::AutoScaling::ScalingPolicy",
      "Properties" : {
        "AdjustmentType" : "ChangeInCapacity",
        "AutoScalingGroupName" : { "Ref" : "LinuxWebASG" },
        "Cooldown" : "300",
        "ScalingAdjustment" : "-1"
      }
    },
    "LinuxWebCloudWatchCPUAlarmHigh" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm",
      "Properties" : {
        "AlarmDescription" : "SNS Notification and scale up if CPU Util is Higher than 90% for 10 mins",
        "MetricName" : "CPUUtilization",
        "Namespace" : "AWS/EC2",
        "Statistic" : "Average",
        "Period" : "300",
        "EvaluationPeriods" : "2",
        "Threshold" : "90",
        "AlarmActions" : [ { "Ref": "LinuxWebAutoscaleUpPolicy" }, { "Ref" : "LinuxWebSNSTopic" } ],
        "Dimensions" : [
          {
            "Name" : "AutoScalingGroupName",
            "Value" : { "Ref" : "LinuxWebASG" }
          }
        ],
        "ComparisonOperator" : "GreaterThanThreshold"
      }
    },
    "LinuxWebCloudWatchCPUAlarmLow" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm",
      "Properties" : {
        "AlarmDescription" : "SNS Notification and scale down if CPU Util is less than 70% for 10 mins",
        "MetricName" : "CPUUtilization",
        "Namespace" : "AWS/EC2",
        "Statistic" : "Average",
        "Period" : "300",
        "EvaluationPeriods" : "2",
        "Threshold" : "70",
        "AlarmActions" : [ { "Ref": "LinuxWebAutoscaleDownPolicy" }, { "Ref" : "LinuxWebSNSTopic" } ],
        "Dimensions" : [
          {
            "Name" : "AutoScalingGroupName",
            "Value" : { "Ref" : "LinuxWebASG" }
          }
        ],
        "ComparisonOperator" : "LessThanThreshold"
      }
    },

    "LinuxWebELB" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer",
      "Properties" : {
        "CrossZone" : true,
        "ConnectionDrainingPolicy": {
          "Enabled" : "true",
          "Timeout" : "60"
        },
        "HealthCheck" :  {
          "Target" : "HTTP:80/index.html",
          "HealthyThreshold" : "3",
          "UnhealthyThreshold" : "3",
          "Interval" : "15",
          "Timeout" : "5"
        },
        "LoadBalancerName" :  "LinuxWebELB",
        "Scheme" : "internet-facing",
        "Listeners" : [
        {
          "LoadBalancerPort" : "80",
          "InstancePort" : "80",
          "InstanceProtocol" : "HTTP",
          "Protocol" :  "HTTP"
        }

         ],
        "SecurityGroups": [ { "Ref": "WebSecurityGroup" } ],
        "Subnets" : { "Ref": "PublicSubnets" },
        "Tags" : [{"Key" : "Network", "Value" : "public"}]
      }
    },
    "WindowsWebSNSTopic" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::SNS::Topic"
    },
    "WindowsWebASG" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup",
      "Properties" : {
        "AvailabilityZones" : { "Ref" : "AZ" },
        "VPCZoneIdentifier" : { "Ref": "PublicSubnets" },
        "MinSize" : "3",
        "MaxSize" : "3",
        "HealthCheckType" : "ELB",
        "HealthCheckGracePeriod" : "600",
        "NotificationConfiguration" : {
          "TopicARN" : { "Ref" : "WindowsWebSNSTopic" },
          "NotificationTypes" : [
            "autoscaling:EC2_INSTANCE_LAUNCH",
            "autoscaling:EC2_INSTANCE_LAUNCH_ERROR",
            "autoscaling:EC2_INSTANCE_TERMINATE",
            "autoscaling:EC2_INSTANCE_TERMINATE_ERROR"
          ]
      },
      "LoadBalancerNames" : [ { "Ref" : "WindowsWebELB" } ],
      "DesiredCapacity" : "3",
      "LaunchConfigurationName" : { "Ref" : "WindowsWebLaunchConfig" },
      "Tags" : [
        {"Key" : "Name", "Value" : "WindowsWebServer", "PropagateAtLaunch" : "true" }
      ]
     }
    },
    "WindowsWebLaunchConfig": {
      "Properties": {
        "AssociatePublicIpAddress" : "true",
        "ImageId": { "Ref": "WindowsAMIID" },
        "InstanceType": { "Ref": "InstanceType" },
        "KeyName": { "Ref": "KeyName" },
        "SecurityGroups": [ { "Ref": "WebSecurityGroup" } ],
        "IamInstanceProfile": { "Ref": "InstanceProfile" },
        "UserData": {
          "Fn::Base64": {
            "Fn::Join": [
              "",
              [
                "<script>\n",
                  "echo hello world > c:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\index.html\n",
                  "hostname >> c:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\index.html\n",
                  "if not exist \"c:\temp\" mkdir c:\temp\n",
                  "powershell.exe -Command Read-S3Object -BucketName aws-codedeploy-us-east-1/latest -Key codedeploy-agent.msi -File c:\\temp\\codedeploy-agent.msi\n",
                  "c:\\temp\\codedeploy-agent.msi /quiet /l c:\\temp\\host-agent-install-log.txt\n",
                  "powershell.exe -Command Get-Service -Name codedeployagent\n",
                "</script>\n"
              ]
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "Type": "AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration"
    },

    "WindowsWebAutoscaleUpPolicy" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::AutoScaling::ScalingPolicy",
      "Properties" : {
        "AdjustmentType" : "ChangeInCapacity",
        "AutoScalingGroupName" : { "Ref" : "WindowsWebASG" },
        "Cooldown" : "300",
        "ScalingAdjustment" : "1"
      }
    },
    "WindowsWebAutoscaleDownPolicy" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::AutoScaling::ScalingPolicy",
      "Properties" : {
        "AdjustmentType" : "ChangeInCapacity",
        "AutoScalingGroupName" : { "Ref" : "WindowsWebASG" },
        "Cooldown" : "300",
        "ScalingAdjustment" : "-1"
      }
    },
    "WindowsWebCloudWatchCPUAlarmHigh" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm",
      "Properties" : {
        "AlarmDescription" : "SNS Notification and scale up if CPU Util is Higher than 90% for 10 mins",
        "MetricName" : "CPUUtilization",
        "Namespace" : "AWS/EC2",
        "Statistic" : "Average",
        "Period" : "300",
        "EvaluationPeriods" : "2",
        "Threshold" : "90",
        "AlarmActions" : [ { "Ref": "WindowsWebAutoscaleUpPolicy" }, { "Ref" : "WindowsWebSNSTopic" } ],
        "Dimensions" : [
          {
            "Name" : "AutoScalingGroupName",
            "Value" : { "Ref" : "WindowsWebASG" }
          }
        ],
        "ComparisonOperator" : "GreaterThanThreshold"
      }
    },
    "WindowsWebCloudWatchCPUAlarmLow" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm",
      "Properties" : {
        "AlarmDescription" : "SNS Notification and scale down if CPU Util is less than 70% for 10 mins",
        "MetricName" : "CPUUtilization",
        "Namespace" : "AWS/EC2",
        "Statistic" : "Average",
        "Period" : "300",
        "EvaluationPeriods" : "2",
        "Threshold" : "70",
        "AlarmActions" : [ { "Ref": "WindowsWebAutoscaleDownPolicy" }, { "Ref" : "WindowsWebSNSTopic" } ],
        "Dimensions" : [
          {
            "Name" : "AutoScalingGroupName",
            "Value" : { "Ref" : "WindowsWebASG" }
          }
        ],
        "ComparisonOperator" : "LessThanThreshold"
      }
    },

    "WindowsWebELB" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer",
      "Properties" : {
        "CrossZone" : true,
        "ConnectionDrainingPolicy": {
          "Enabled" : "true",
          "Timeout" : "60"
        },
        "HealthCheck" :  {
          "Target" : "HTTP:80/index.html",
          "HealthyThreshold" : "3",
          "UnhealthyThreshold" : "3",
          "Interval" : "15",
          "Timeout" : "5"
        },
        "LoadBalancerName" :  "WindowsWebELB",
        "Scheme" : "internet-facing",
        "Listeners" : [
        {
          "LoadBalancerPort" : "80",
          "InstancePort" : "80",
          "InstanceProtocol" : "HTTP",
          "Protocol" :  "HTTP"
        }

         ],
        "SecurityGroups": [ { "Ref": "WebSecurityGroup" } ],
        "Subnets" : { "Ref": "PublicSubnets" },
        "Tags" : [{"Key" : "Network", "Value" : "public"}]
      }
    }

  },
  "Outputs" : {
    "LinuxWebFQDN" : { "Value": { "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "LinuxWebELB", "DNSName" ]} },
    "WindowsWebFQDN" : { "Value": { "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "WindowsWebELB", "DNSName" ]} }
  }
}
```

but I got some errors in the creation step:

```
21:44:58 UTC+0200   DELETE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup WebSecurityGroup    
    21:44:56 UTC+0200   DELETE_COMPLETE AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer LinuxWebELB 
    21:44:55 UTC+0200   DELETE_COMPLETE AWS::SNS::Topic LinuxWebSNSTopic    
    21:44:54 UTC+0200   DELETE_COMPLETE AWS::SNS::Topic WindowsWebSNSTopic  
    21:44:54 UTC+0200   DELETE_COMPLETE AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer WindowsWebELB   
    21:44:54 UTC+0200   DELETE_COMPLETE AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration   LinuxWebLaunchConfig    
    21:44:53 UTC+0200   DELETE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration   LinuxWebLaunchConfig    
    21:44:53 UTC+0200   DELETE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer LinuxWebELB 
    21:44:53 UTC+0200   DELETE_COMPLETE AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration   WindowsWebLaunchConfig  
    21:44:53 UTC+0200   DELETE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::SNS::Topic WindowsWebSNSTopic  
    21:44:53 UTC+0200   DELETE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::SNS::Topic LinuxWebSNSTopic    
    21:44:53 UTC+0200   DELETE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer WindowsWebELB   
    21:44:47 UTC+0200   ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS    AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  Infra   The following resource(s) failed to create: [WindowsWebLaunchConfig, LinuxWebELB, WindowsWebELB]. . Rollback requested by user.
    21:44:46 UTC+0200   CREATE_FAILED   AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer LinuxWebELB Resource creation cancelled
    21:44:45 UTC+0200   CREATE_FAILED   AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer WindowsWebELB   Resource creation cancelled
    21:44:45 UTC+0200   CREATE_COMPLETE AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration   LinuxWebLaunchConfig    
    21:44:44 UTC+0200   CREATE_FAILED   AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration   WindowsWebLaunchConfig  AMI cannot be described
    21:44:44 UTC+0200   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer WindowsWebELB   Resource creation Initiated
    21:44:44 UTC+0200   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration   LinuxWebLaunchConfig    Resource creation Initiated
    21:44:44 UTC+0200   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration   WindowsWebLaunchConfig  
    21:44:43 UTC+0200   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration   LinuxWebLaunchConfig    
    21:44:43 UTC+0200   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer LinuxWebELB 
    21:44:43 UTC+0200   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer WindowsWebELB   
    21:44:39 UTC+0200   CREATE_COMPLETE AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup WebSecurityGroup    
    21:44:37 UTC+0200   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup WebSecurityGroup    Resource creation Initiated
    21:44:32 UTC+0200   CREATE_COMPLETE AWS::SNS::Topic WindowsWebSNSTopic  
    21:44:31 UTC+0200   CREATE_COMPLETE AWS::SNS::Topic LinuxWebSNSTopic    
    21:44:21 UTC+0200   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::SNS::Topic WindowsWebSNSTopic  Resource creation Initiated
    21:44:21 UTC+0200   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::SNS::Topic WindowsWebSNSTopic  
    21:44:20 UTC+0200   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup WebSecurityGroup    
    21:44:20 UTC+0200   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::SNS::Topic LinuxWebSNSTopic    Resource creation Initiated
    21:44:19 UTC+0200   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::SNS::Topic LinuxWebSNSTopic    
    21:44:12 UTC+0200   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  Infra   User Initiated
```

Comment: Thank you for putting the full post despite the answerers request to make a minimal example. This has been a helpful example for me of an entire file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your WindowsAMIID (`ami-f7482692`) doesn't exist anymore. You can try searching for it in the EC2 console to see what I mean. [It shows up on some AMI indexing site as 'deregistered'](http://thecloudmarket.com/image/ami-f7482692--windows-server-2008-r2-sp1-english-64bit-sql-2008-r2-sp2-express-2015-09-09#/definition).

In the future please create a [**minimal** example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue combining Packer EC2 builds with CDK. As the other answers said, it's essentially a 404 on the AMI ID which didn't initially make sense to me as I was using a CDK lookup on name/account rather than an explicit AMI ID.

The reason it wasn't working is that CDK caches AMI lookups in the `cdk.context.json` file.

By deleting this file and adding it to the `.gitignore` file, the builds started passing again.